Import New Google Sheet table to Another Spreadsheet
I know that google sheets just recently released the new table features, and I am currently using them.
I want to import the table named "gs_ob1" from the spreadsheet with ID "1sjgB7dyKYop0OVe9_4IxWek9IlVjtD9WUyoGzjuSkis" to another spreadsheet (different file) with all of the latest features.
This is my syntax: =ARRAYFORMULA(1sjgB7dyKYop0OVe9_4IxWek9IlVjtD9WUyoGzjuSkis, gs_ob1) However, this did not work. I don't want to use IMPORTRANGE because some new features of the table will be disabled (e.g. dropdown, checkboxes, etc).
If I use ARRAYFORMULA function to import the table from one sheet to another sheet within the same spreadsheet (same file), the features will also be imported.  I used this Syntax:  =ARRAYFORMULA(gs_ob1) and it worked. (link of the video here to show this worked)
But I want to import the table (not the range) to another spreadsheet. How can I achieve this without using IMPORTRANGE or QUERY? Appscript? Macros?

Can you maybe share a screenshot showcasing how the features are enabled on your end after pulling data from a table using the formula =ARRAYFORMULA(gs_ob1)?!

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tXIYZkP9qmJQraEbZqKw8ePkOjtlEUIo/view?usp=sharing the video can be found here

yes its not possible to importrange table ID as of now but supplying the table range works good with enabling the features of the table (just as shown in your video) SCREENSHOT

Oh I didn't realize I can do that with importrange as well, not just arrayformula!! Thanks for making me realize!!

It's very likely that the formula =ARRAYFORMULA(1sjgB7dyKYop0OVe9_4IxWek9IlVjtD9WUyoGzjuSkis, gs_ob1) doesn't "work" because the parameters are not appropriate.
However, there isn't a built-in feature to import a table from another spreadsheet. It's worth noting that the table feature was introduced very recently. Google Apps Script and the Google Sheets API might take a while to add methods to handle tables.
One possible workaround is to copy the whole sheet by using SpreadsheetApp.Spreadsheet.copyTo.
As you already know, to import data from another spreadsheet, use IMPORTRANGE. Please bear in mind that this function requires text values as parameters. You might put those values in cells and use the corresponding cell references as parameters.

Thanks for your response. I tried to use SpreadsheetApp.Spreasheet.copyTo in Appscript, but it functioned the same as IMPORTRANGE. I want other features to work as well after importing the table. Importing the table containing all the new features, from one sheet to another sheet within the same spreadsheet is possible using the ARRAYFORMULA. Hmm I guess I'll just have to wait
